# start() method of QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager is not updating the system properties

Tags: java, testing, quarkus

In a setup as described in the [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#altering-the-test-class):

```java
public class MyWireMockResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8090);
        wireMockServer.start();

        // create some stubs

        return Map.of("some.service.url", "localhost:" + wireMockServer.port());
    }

    //...
}
```

How can I access the value returned in in the `start()` method.

The [javadoc](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/58cc7fb85891eb3b2f47c6a9a4db172393315b4f/test-framework/common/src/main/java/io/quarkus/test/common/QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager.java#L28-L33) says:

> A map of system properties that should be set for the running test

Why "should be"?

I would like to set some values that I can later used in my productive code.

I have tried: `System.getProperty("some.service.url")`

I have also tried:

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "some.service.url") 
String serviceUrl;
```

But the value is not set.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system properties mentioned in the javadoc is confusing. The returned map will as expected override the configurations.

It was not working for me to access it with the `@ConfigProperty` annotation because I was reading the value in the constructor and not in the method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeBean {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "some.service.url")
    String serviceUrl;

    public SomeBean() {
        // we are too early here, value is null:
        System.out.println("value in constructor: " + serviceUrl);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        System.out.println("value in init: " + serviceUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/26710 fixes the Javadoc issue.